# Variable is count total from all clinics within unit that reported cases, some didn't report. How do I deal with this type of missingness?

Tags: time-series, missing-data, count-data

This is the first time I have posted (but I have read a fair few threads on this site before).

This question is quite general in nature since I don't know where to start, or maybe I don't know the terminology. Please be patient, as this issue is difficult to explain. I have scoured the internet for a solution but I think I'm searching in the wrong places. I am familiar with both multiple imputation and time series, and have published studies using these methods before. I have a specific question on how to handle a specific type of missingness in a time series context.

I am working on data from Chad, and the outcome measure is monthly number of reported malaria cases per health district. I have data for 5 years and around 40 districts eligible for inclusion in the analytic sample.

My problem is missingness. There are few missing months for any district overall (i.e. when there was no case reporting at all from the district), but my problem is partial reporting within districts). Each district has between 4 to 21 health clinics, and numbers of cases are reported to the district level and added together to give a monthly count of cases. Around half of the time all clinics in the district reported, but just as often a number of clinics within the district will not report their monthly totals. Although I know how many clinics out of the district total reported their malaria cases and how many did not, I cannot obtain a breakdown of the numbers of cases from each clinic that did report and do not know which specific clinics did not report (i.e. I can only work with district totals).

Here is a made up but representative example:

In March 2015 N'Djamena North has a total of 10 clinics. Of these 10, 8 of them reported a total of 400 cases. I do not know which 2 clinics did not report or how many cases occurred at each of the 8 clinics that did report. In this case the total of 400 cases is certainly below the actual number, as it does not include the two missing clinics (which presuably had cases but didn't report anything).

Using my example, I had some initial ideas on how to deal with this:

1. Complete case (not ideal): Only use daya from months when all clinics reported. This will reduce my number of observations and could lead to bias as I can't assume partial non-reporting occurs complely at random.
2. Scale-up: If 8 clinics reported 8 cases and the other two are unknown, then I could simply multiply 400 by (10/8) to get 500 cases in that month. The problem is that, with no information on the missing clinics, I am not sure I can simply assume each had 50 cases (i.e. I don't know if the clinics that did report are representative of the ones that didn't). Furthermore, clinics are different sizes, and if, for example, smaller clinics covering smaller catchments of patients are more likely to not report, then the total would likely be less than 500.
3. Go ahead with the analysis and just adjust for percent of clinics missing (simple, but I presume that it has similar problems to the last solution).
4. Use some sort of imputation method. Districts with all clinics reporting in a given month would be considered complete, but for incomplete districts I could impute using cases reported and the proportion of clinics reporting. Would that work? Is there some issue I am missing? What if in the example above, the value was imputed at less than 400?

Alternatively, is there some other method I haven't considered?

Thanks everyone. I would be grateful for any insight. Apologies for the long-winded post.

Best regards

Dr Sol Richardson

Epidemiologist in Seasonal Malaria Chemoprevention at Malaria Consortium